How do I make a perfect curve in Inkscape and build my drawing on it
So, I'm trying to recreate the Firefox logo for practice but I'm struggling to draw the curve/circle that the fox follows along the entire logo.
I can't manipulate the nodes as well as I would like and it seems extra wonky everywhere.

I have tried to draw a spiro path here and somehow put the vector on that curve so it's all sleek and a proper circle on the bottom (you can see in the center too where the ball is that it's not a good curve on my redesign) but I'm stuck.
Overall it's wonky, especially the head part and down.
Edit:
I came up with this after the answer which helped lots. As you can tell, the nodes somewhere are still pretty choppy and I need more practice with the bezier pen and curves.

Now the problem that I'm left with is I've removed the black stroke and I'm left with too much space between the objects? I have tried to duplicate them but it didn't change a thing unless I wanna duplicate a million times.

Use the circle tool to get as close to the curves as possible. Then move the arc controls.

Then do Path > Object to Path, to convert the shape to paths. From here you can make small adjustments to the position of the nodes, and the curve handles to get the best match possible.

And the rest is more or less plain sailing


Draw all the curves, making sure to create overlaps so you can cut all the pieces up later

Overall, make sure you have as few nodes as possible. This is the trick to getting smooth curves. If possible, don't add more than you need. You can also delete extra nodes you may have placed, and Inkscape will automatically smooth the curves between them.

Solidify all the pieces using the Shape Builder tool

Apply fill colours to each, and you are about 90% there.


All you have to do now is add some gradients. Original raster image (left), vector (right)

